# how to directly send base 64 encoded string of image in google cloud vision API?

Tags: python, json, google-cloud-platform, encode, google-vision

im using the following code and it sees like client.text_detection has to take in an image. instead, I want to send just the base64 encoded text string of the image. what is the best way to do this?

```
def detect_text(path): """Detects text in the file.""" client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    with io.open(path, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
    
    image = vision.Image(content=content)
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    texts = response.text_annotations
    print('Texts:')
    
    for text in texts:
        print('\n"{}"'.format(text.description))
    
        vertices = (['({},{})'.format(vertex.x, vertex.y)
                    for vertex in text.bounding_poly.vertices])
    
        print('bounds: {}'.format(','.join(vertices)))
    
    if response.error.message:
        raise Exception(
            '{}\nFor more info on error messages, check: '
            'https://cloud.google.com/apis/design/errors'.format(
                response.error.message))
```

Comment: It looks like you are sending the image content in the request. Are you getting an error? What is the error?

Comment: As per your code, I assume that you are following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Ftielve-test%22%2C%22requests%22%3A%5B%7B%22image%22%3A%7B%22source%22%3A%7B%22gcsImageUri%22%3A%22gs%3A%2F%2Ftemp-empty%2Fwelcome-sign-home-page.png%22%7D%7D%2C%22features%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22TEXT_DETECTION%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D%7D#detect_text_in_a_local_image).You don't need to base64 encode with this python example, it works with the path of your image.

Comment: If you still want to send only the base64 encoded string, can you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score -1):

```
uploadImage() async {
const url = 'input web url here';
const header = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json",
  "Api-Key": "input key here"
};`enter code here`
if(uploadimage == null) return;
String base64Image = base64Encode(uploadimage.readAsBytesSync());

var body = jsonEncode({
  'images': [base64Image],
 
});

final response = await http.post(url, headers: header, body: body);


print(response.statusCode);
```